# How to change catcode in environment

Tags: environments, catcodes

I try to locally change catcode in environment

```
\newenvironment{wse}
{
  \catcode`^=\active%
  \def^{\mathchar\numexpr"7000+`\^\relax}%
  $
}
{
  $
}
```

but the next code

```
\begin{wse}
  x^2
\end{wse}
```

breaks with

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `\newenvironment`, the category code of `^` is 7 and this is not changed by `` \catcode`^=\active ``.

```
\begingroup
\catcode`^=\active
\gdef\changehat{\def^{\mathchar\numexpr"7000+`\^\relax}}
\endgroup

\newenvironment{wse}
 {%
  \catcode`^=\active
  \changehat
  $%
 }
 {%
  $%
 }
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\catcode`^=\active
\gdef\changehat{\def^{\mathchar\numexpr"7000+`\^\relax}}
\endgroup

\newenvironment{wse}
 {%
  \catcode`^=\active
  \changehat
  $%
 }
 {%
  $%
 }

\begin{document}

X$a^b$X\begin{wse}a^b\end{wse}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative with the `\lowercase` trick that assumes `~` is active.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{wse}
 {%
  \catcode`^=\active
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^ \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{\mathchar\numexpr"7000+`\^\relax}}%
  $%
 }
 {%
  $%
 }

\begin{document}

X$a^b$X\begin{wse}a^b\end{wse}X

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works like a charm! It look's like this is the only way i forget to try. It's because for some days i work on custom env and pretty tired to deal with TeX kind of matryoshka, i mean definition, redef, create local scope and so on. Thank you!

Comment: @user6786661 Remember that a `\def` only stores character tokens with the category code they have at the moment the definition is made and that `\def` does no interpretation whatsoever of the tokens in the body. The above indirect method is one of the tricks to use; there exist variations on the theme, I showed also one of them.

Comment: It seems to be possible to put `\changehat` outside of the environment (eg just after the `\endgroup`.  Is this incorrect, or is there any reason to prefer placing it in the environment?

Comment: @JeanPierre What line are you referring to? The group is essential to have the proper category code of `^` at definition time.

Comment: I mean moving \changehat from the wse env definition to a global location, ie just after the \endgroup.  This seems to work on this example so I'm just wondering.

Comment: @JeanPierre This would make `^` active everywhere, with the impossibility of using it for superscripts.

Comment: No  it does not, since just the \changehat is moved, not the \catcode thing.  Try it!

Comment: @JeanPierre Oh, sure. But my code has the advantage that you can have several versions of the active `^` in different environments.

Comment: Indeed, thanks!