# Code redefining ampersand stops working when put in command

Tags: active-characters

I want to redefine `&` in a *command*. I tried to adapt [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392770/82912) code that redefines `^` in an environment but couldn't make it work.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myampersand}{?}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392770/82912
\begingroup%
\catcode`&=\active%
\gdef\redefineampersand{\def&{\myampersand}}%
\endgroup%

\begingroup%
\catcode`&=\active%
\redefineampersand%
a & b
\endgroup%

\newenvironment{newampersandenv}{%
    \catcode`&=\active%
    \redefineampersand%
}{}
\begin{newampersandenv}
    a & b
\end{newampersandenv}

% I would like to do this but it doesn't work:
\newcommand{\newampersandcmd}[1]{
    \begin{newampersandenv}
        #1
    \end{newampersandenv}
}
%\newampersandcmd{a & b} % Misplaced alignment tab character &. \newampersandcmd{a & b}

% I tried to write it another way but none of those work:

\newcommand{\testa}{
    \begin{newampersandenv}
        a & b
    \end{newampersandenv}
}
%\testa % Misplaced alignment tab character &. \testa

\newcommand{\testb}{
    \catcode`&=\active%
    \redefineampersand%
    a & b
}
%\testb % Misplaced alignment tab character &. \testb

\newcommand{\testc}{
    \catcode`&=\active%
    \redefineampersand%
    \begingroup
    a & b
    \endgroup
}
%\testc % Misplaced alignment tab character &. \testc

\newcommand{\testd}{
    \begingroup
    \catcode`&=\active%
    \redefineampersand%
    a & b
    \endgroup
}
%\testd % Misplaced alignment tab character &. \testd

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record: For some use cases, it would probably be easier to replace `&`s instead of redefining it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54987/82912

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myampersand}{?}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392770/82912
\begingroup%
\catcode`&=\active%
\gdef\redefineampersand{\def&{\myampersand}}%
\endgroup%

\begingroup%
\catcode`&=\active%
\redefineampersand%
a & b
\endgroup%

\newenvironment{newampersandenv}{%
    \catcode`&=\active%
    \redefineampersand%
}{}
\begin{newampersandenv}
    a & b
\end{newampersandenv}

% I would like to do this but it doesn't work:
\def\newampersandcmd{%
  \begin{newampersandenv}%
  \@newampersandcmd%
}

\def\@newampersandcmd#1{%
      #1%
  \end{newampersandenv}%
}

\newampersandcmd{a & b}

% I tried to write it another way but none of those work:

\begingroup
\catcode`&=\active
\gdef\testa{%
    \begin{newampersandenv}%
        a & b%
    \end{newampersandenv}%
}
\endgroup

\testa

\begingroup
\catcode`&=\active
\gdef\testb{%
    \redefineampersand%
    a & b%
}
\endgroup

\testb

\end{document}
```

What is happening is a difference of what rules are in force when TeX *reads* the commands (*i.e.* executes the `\newcommand`s), and the rules when TeX *executes* the defined commands.

Let's use, for example, this macro:

```
\newcommand{\testa}{%
  \catcode`&=\active
  a & b%
}
```

When TeX *reads* the `\newcommand` it turns the input into a list of tokens, and each token has a `cat`egory `code` assigned. But the `catcode`s that are assigned are the ones that are in force when the command is read, so `a & b` will be translated to `catcode`s `11 10 4 10 11` which are, respectively, letter, space, alignment tab, space, and letter. But the `\catcode`&=\active`was never executed when TeX was reading the command, so the`&` was still an alignment tab character.

When TeX will execute this command, it will change the `catcode` of `&` to `\active`, then write the list of tokens `a & b` with the `catcode`s `11 10 4 10 11`. The `catcode` of the tokens didn't change form the definition time to the execution time.

However, if you move the `catcode` change *outside* the command definition:

```
\catcode`&=\active
\newcommand{\testa}{%
  a & b%
}
```

TeX will read `a & b` with `catcode`s `11 10 13 10 11`, and from now on every time the macro `\testa` is used, these will be the `catcode`s that TeX will use, independently from the `catcode`s that are in force when the command is used.

This is the reason that the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` thing work. When you define an "internal" LaTeX command with an `@` in the name you do, for example:

```
\makeatletter
\def\wrappermacro{%
  \my@m@cr@withm@ny@@@@%
}
\def\my@m@cr@withm@ny@@@@{hello}
\makeatother
```

the `catcode` of the `@` is changed to `11` at the time the command is *defined* and changed back to `12` shortly after. And when you use the `\wrappermacro`, the `\my@m@cr@withm@ny@@@@` will work without problems because the `catcode`s that were in force at the *definition* time are the ones that count.

Comment: Thank you! I really don't understand why this fix is needed when the `&` is directly in the body of the command thought.

Comment: @xavierm02 Ulrike Fischer said I'm more or less correct so... I think that with your version of the command, TeX somehow reads the `&` *before* doing the `\catcode` change, thus the error. My version, on the other hand, first does the `\catcode` change (by calling `\begin{newampersandenv}`), and only then calls the `\@newampersandcmd`, which reads the arguments and writes the `&` with the new `\catcode`.

Comment: @xavierm02 Ooh, and when they are in the body of the command, I think it's the same principle. TeX reads the body of the command without expanding anything, so the `&` still means an alignment tab. Maybe if the command is defined with an `\edef` that wouldn't happen. I'll check this later and add to the answer :)

Comment: The real reason is that with the OP's definition, in `\newampersandcmd{1&2}` the `&` is absorbed and tokenized *before* `\redefineampersand` is executed, so the category code of `&` is still 4 and such remains forever.

Comment: @xavierm02 See my updated answer :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik many thanks for this answer! I was trying to embed a definition like `\newampersandcmd` into an enclosing command, but got a strange behaviour and I was wondering whether you would know what the problem could be. If I define a simple command `\NewDocumentCommand{\DoSomethingFunny}{m}{\newampersandcmd{#1}}`, the error message `Misplaced...` appears. But `\DoSomethingFunny{\the\catcode`&}` will return `13` - so I thought `&` must have the correct catcode at time of execution?

Comment: @FelixEmanuel The problem is that `\newampersandcmd` first changes the catcode of `&`, and _then_ grabs the argument, whereas your `\DoSomethingFunny` command first grabs, then changes the catcode, and that order does not work because when it grabs the argument, TeX freezes the catcode of the grabbed `&` character (catcode 4).  ``\DoSomethingFunny{\the\catcode`&}`` then says 13 because it queries the current catcode associated with the character `&`, and not the catcode of _that_ `&` token. This is the same issue that trying to put something verbatim in a definition like `\def\x{\verb|&|} \x`.

Answer (score 1):

My final goal was to have a way to build a macro `\makearraysfake` such that `\makearraysfake[?]{\begin{array}{ll}a&b\end{array}}` behaves exactly like `a?b`. In other words, I wanted to remove all arrays, and merge all the cells (on a line) by concatenating the contents with some given delimiter in between. The following code does this.

(My use case for this was that I use LyX and use arrays to allow putting as many arguments as I want in some enumeration, but I didn't like the spaces added by array.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}



% Define global versions of \newcommand and \renewcommand
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51750/82912
\makeatletter
\def\gnewcommand{\g@star@or@long\gnew@command}
\def\grenewcommand{\g@star@or@long\grenew@command}
\def\g@star@or@long#1{% 
    \@ifstar{\let\l@ngrel@x\global#1}{\def\l@ngrel@x{\long\global}#1}}
\def\gnew@command#1{\@testopt{\@gnewcommand#1}0}
\def\@gnewcommand#1[#2]{%
    \kernel@ifnextchar [{\@gxargdef#1[#2]}%
    {\@argdef#1[#2]}}
\let\@gxargdef\@xargdef
\patchcmd{\@gxargdef}{\def}{\gdef}{}{}
\let\grenew@command\renew@command
\patchcmd{\grenew@command}{\new@command}{\gnew@command}{}{}
\makeatother



% This macro is used to apply the trick of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422603/82912
\newcommand{\identityendgroup}[1]{%
    #1%
    \endgroup%
}%

% The \makearraysfake command takes two arguments and returns the second one where arrays are removed (but their content remains) and ampersands are replaced by the first argument.
\begingroup%
\catcode`&=\active%

\gnewcommand{\makearraysfake}[1][]{
    \begingroup%
    \catcode`&=\active%
    \def&{#1}%
    \renewenvironment{array}[2][]{}{}%
    \identityendgroup%
}%

\gnewcommand{\makeampersandactive}{
    \begingroup%
    \catcode`&=\active%
    \def&{}%
    \identityendgroup%
}

\endgroup%

\begin{document}

It prevents the errors when \& is used in the second argument, and replaces it by the first argument:

$$
%\boxed{a&b} % Misplaced alignment tab character &. $$\boxed{a&b}
%\not= 
\makearraysfake[b]{\boxed{a&c}}
=
\boxed{abc}
$$

It removes the spaces added by array:

$$
\boxed{
    \begin{array}{ll}
    a&c
    \end{array}
}
\not=
\makearraysfake[]{
    \boxed{
        \begin{array}{ll}
        a&b
        \end{array}
    }
}
=
\boxed{ab}
$$

It can be used in other macros, provided that they are placed in a \textbackslash makeampersandactive macro:

\newcommand{\identity}[1]{#1}

$$
\makeampersandactive{
    \identity{
        \makearraysfake[]{
            \boxed{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                a&b
                \end{array}
            }
        }
    }
}
$$

\end{document}
```